# Possible reasons why SPA application views won't communicate with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So I have a bit of a mindboggler on my hands that's refusing to bend. My objective is to log on a database every single time a page is visited. I have created on the c# side code that logs this info and I know it works. What I'm trying to do now is relatively straightfoward; every time an item (that is, a page) is clicked on the home view list (which acts as a shell for the SPA and doesnt change), send the page name to a function in Javascript which will in turn communicate to the Webmethod. The problem is, when the app starts, as it is a SPA, it collects all the divs (see below) and renders them and for some reason, it does not want to communicate and pass parameters into the javascript function, no matter where I put it (I've put it on a header, I've put it underneath the html, etc). The onclick function works fine when test it separately, but in this application, it refuses to work.

I've also tried using 'body onload="PostName();" as well as window.onload on each of the pages to invoke the function but its also a blank. Some thoughts on where the problem might be?

```
<tr class="row">
        <td>
            <div class="tabbable">
                <ul class="nav nav-tabs nav-stacked" id="menuTabs">
                    <li class="active"><a href="#land" data-toggle="tab" onclick="javascript:PostName('Home')">Home</a></li>
                    <li class=""><a href="#tutuwaroadshow" data-toggle="tab" onclick="javascript:PostName('Roadshows')">Tutuwa roadshows</a></li>
                    <li class=""><a href="#faqsandpresentations" data-toggle="tab" onclick="javascript:PostName('Faqs')">FAQ's and presentations</a></li>
                    <li class=""><a href="#examplescenarios" data-toggle="tab" onclick="javascript:PostName('ExampleScenarios')">Example scenarios</a></li>
                    <li class=""><a href="#financialadvisors" data-toggle="tab" onclick="javascript:PostName('FinancialAdvisors')">Financial advisors</a></li>
                    <!--<li class=""><a href="#privateclients" data-toggle="tab">Private Clients</a></li>-->
                    <li class=""><a href="#trustdeeds" data-toggle="tab" onclick="javascript:PostName('TrustDeeds')">Trust deeds</a></li>
                    <li class=""><a href="#newsflashes" data-toggle="tab" onclick="javascript:PostName('Newsflashes')">Newsflashes</a></li>
                    <li class=""><a href="#usefullinksandcontacts" data-toggle="tab" onclick="javascript:PostName('Useful')">Useful links and contacts</a></li>
                    <li class=""><a href="#webinar" data-toggle="tab" onclick="javascript:PostName('Webinar')">Webinar</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="newsflash"><a href="~/Content/files/Tutuwa%20Newsflash%204.pdf" target="_blank">Click here for the latest newsflash.</a></div>
        </td>
        <td rowspan="2">
            <div class="tab-content">
                <div class="tab-pane active" id="land">@Html.Partial("Land")</div>
                <div class="tab-pane" id="tutuwaroadshow">@Html.Partial("TutuwaRoadshow")</div>
                <div class="tab-pane" id="faqsandpresentations">@Html.Partial("FaqsAndPresentations")</div>
                <div class="tab-pane" id="examplescenarios">@Html.Partial("ExampleScenarios")</div>
                <div class="tab-pane" id="financialadvisors">@Html.Partial("FinancialAdvisors") </div>
                <div class="tab-pane" id="privateclients">@Html.Partial("PrivateClients")</div>
                <div class="tab-pane" id="trustdeeds">@Html.Partial("TrustDeeds")</div>
                <div class="tab-pane" id="newsflashes">@Html.Partial("NewsFlashes")</div>
                <div class="tab-pane" id="usefullinksandcontacts">@Html.Partial("UsefulLinksAndContacts")</div>
                <div class="tab-pane" id="webinar">@Html.Partial("Webinar")</div>
            </div>            

        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

the function, currently sitting on the header:

```
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function PostName(pageName) {
    debugger;
    //String PageName = "ExampleScenarios";
    $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: 'HomeController/SaveVisitorHits',
    data: { s: pageName },
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (msg) {
    //do nothing
    },
    error: function (e) {
    // do nothing
    }
    });
    }
    </script>

    <title></title>
</head>
```

Note that when I seperate this code from the app, it works fine (see http://jsfiddle.net/cLp6y51c/ as was created by another user who was trying to help earlier on). The problem is within the application, maybe some sort of setting that I'm not aware of.

This is the alternate method I've tried on each of the pages but also doesnt work:

```
<header>
    <img src="../../content/images/examplescenarios-header.jpg" style="height: 340px" />


    <script type="text/javascript">
        function PostName() {
            debugger;
            //String PageName = "ExampleScenarios";
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: 'HomeController/SaveVisitorHits',
                data: { s: "ExampleScenarios" },
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (msg) {
                    //do nothing
                },
                error: function (e) {
                    // do nothing
                }
            });
        }

        window.onload = PostName;
    </script>

</header>

<body onload="PostName();">
```

Comment: In the jsfiddle on the "Tutuwa roadshows" link there is a `data-bind` attribute. Do you use MVC HTML helper class? Are you sure you have all references for javascript files the HTML helper uses?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are making a call to a wrong URL. I presume it is a .NET MVC app? In .NET MVC you don't put the word `Controller` in the URL. The URL should be `Home/SaveVisitorHits`

Comment: oh alright thanks.. i will change that.. But the code doesn't get there because the onclick function doesnt seem to be connecting with the function..